# Why this function return nothing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use Angular Providers. While i call master.parameters() I got nothing. Why ?

```
       masterApp.provider('master',[function() { 
          this.$get = function()
          {
                return {

                    parameters: function() {
                        var data="hai";
                        return
                           data;

                    }
                };

          };

    }]);
```

Comment: Where/when/how are you "calling master.parameters()"?

Comment: don't put a newline after a `return` - javascript hates you when you do that and "infers" a `;` after the `return`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: really, the problem is clearly stated and clearly shown

Comment: @JaromandaX You have clearly answered it too, should make it and answer not a comment :) I was coming here to do exactly that but you were first.

Comment: no - this has probably been answered before - I just haven't searched yet

Comment: @Jaromanda. Yaa return statement is working if the return data is on the same line. But I have to do some operations before returning data. What Should I do ?

Comment: do them before the return statement

Comment: @ Jaromanda. Now It's Working. Sorry for this silly mistake. Thanks for your answer while every others hated me. I merely wasted 1 hr on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript was a language written in a handful of days, therefore it has many many many quirks that have never been, and probably wont ever be, eradicated for fear of breaking the internets

one of these is javascripts loose, very very loose, requirement for statement termination by the good ol' semi-colon - the Javascript Engine "infers" where this should be

one place all Javascript Engines seem to agree to get wrong consistently, despite the "unreachable code after return statement" error that is invariably output in the console by reputable browsers, is the humble return statement

```
return
   'value'
```

is always interpreted as

```
return;
value;
```

the most common gotcha is returning an object, some people like to have the open and close braces on their own line so they write the return statement as

```
return 
{
    key: value,
    key2: value
}
```

which, as we've seen will be interpreted as

```
return;
{
    key: value,
    key2: value
};
```

with a console message about unreachable code after a return statement

This is why it's a good idea to jshint/jslint your code - or at least look at the console for errors like this

Comment: silly? I works with seasoned programmers who get caught by this - I jshint/jslint my code so in this regard I'm perfect :p

Answer (score 0):

newline after a return is only problem. Thanks @aromandaX